# MOSFET not fully OFF when Gate Voltage is 0V

Tags: power-supply, power, mosfet, power-electronics

A [N-channel MOSFET STP16NF06L](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1690175.pdf) is used to drive a 12V load.

[image]

Pin 1 is connected to Arduino Uno digital pin 4.

Pin 2 is connected to the negative terminal of the 12V load.

Pin 3 is connected to the GND terminal of a 12VDC power supply.

The positive terminal of the 12V load is connected to the +12V terminal of the 12VDC power supply.

**Problem:** When the Arduino output pin is at `LOW` state and measured to be at 0V, the MOSFET still turns on and passes 6V to the 12V load.

When the output pin is in the `HIGH` state, it's measured to be at 4.9V and 7.5V across the 12V load.

Shouldnt the MOSFET provide 0V across the load when pin 1 is 0V, and just above 10V when pin 1 is at 5V?

---

[image]

Pin 1: Green clip to Arduino pin

Pin 2: White clip to negative terminal of load

Pin 3: Black clip to GND of 12V power supply

Comment: Are you sure you don't have D and S wired opposite? Measure with a voltmeter from Gate to Source and see if that is 0V.

Comment: What is the load?

Comment: @ACD I swaped the connections to `D` and `S`, and its always 11V across the load irregardless of whether we send 0V or 5V to the G pin. It's 0.497V from Gate to Source.

Comment: Also you should use your multimeter to find the forward diode (0.6 volts or something).

Comment: Maybe the arduino output can't sink current?  (Add a resistor from gate to ground ... maybe 10 k ohm)

Comment: is your power supply's ground the Arduino's ground?

Comment: @PkP Arduino is powered by a PC's USB port instead of the power supply. Will doing so mess things up?

Comment: The way you describe the connection, it should have a common ground; otherwise you can't say what the Vgs voltage will be

Comment: You need at least 1V Gate to Source to pass 250uA so if you're measuring 0.497V I have no idea how the FET can be on.

Comment: @ACD, it's conducting through the forward diode. Seems clear to me that it's a problem of not having a common ground.

Comment: @PkP [My power supply](http://www.deltapsu.com/FntProductsAction.do?method=openItemDetail&productId=122) has 2 output voltages and hence 2 ground terminals. Is it OK to connect the MOSFET to the GND for 24V ouput, and Aarduino to the GND for 5V output?

Comment: From your description I can't be really sure what your circuit is like. But can you arrange your connection so that all the power supplies, including the PC USB's grounds are connected together?

Comment: You must have a common ground. If you really measured 0V **at the MOSFET** from G to S then that isn't the problem.

Comment: @PkP I've connected the Arduino GND to the power supply GND. Gate to Source is now 0.028V when Arduino output pin is 0.13V, and it's 9.8V across the load. When Arduino output is 1.3V, Gate to Source is 1.22V, and it's 10.3V across the load.

Comment: I added a picture, is your connection like the picture now? (Drain upwards and Source downwards)

Comment: @PkP Yes its like in your diagram.

Comment: Want to add that when setting the Arduino output pin to `HIGH`, multimeter measures only 1.3V from output pin to GND.

Comment: Hmm, Spehro already asked... What's the load? Ummm... 1.3V? That means that either the terminal is not Gate, there's something else connected or something is broken.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The load is a [thermoelectric cooler](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Laird-Technologies-Thermal-Solutions/DA-044-12-02-00-00/?qs=sRTx%2FtA2SD9ZnH6LhR%252b%252b1w%3D%3D)

Comment: Is that load working correctly? How about you replace the load with a 1K or 10K resistor and try again? And double check that there are no short circuits and that the FET pinout is correct. Also, since you report that you only get 1.3V output high from the Arduino to the gate, disconnect the gate and measure again what the voltage is without the FET connected.

Comment: @PkP The load works perfectly when connecting it directly to the 12V power supply. FET pinouts looks correct to me...

Comment: @Nyxynyx And the Peltier was connected during these tests?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yup peltier was connected all the while. Looks like I should try with a resister instead of the peltier.

Comment: You need to restart your debugging procedure. Start with nothing and establish a base of known facts, starting from measuring that you can switch the output pin of your microcontroller high and low, and what the output voltages are. Then add connections one at a time and establish that all your known facts are still valid. Continue until you find an impossibility or you get your device working 100%. When you find an impossibility, solve it before trying something else.

Comment: @PkP Turns out the MOSFET may have burnt out doing 6A without a heatsink. Replaced the MOSFET with a new one and MOSFET drain to ground gives the full 12V when Arduino output pin is `HIGH`, and 0V when `LOW`.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought about that when I wrote that "something is broken" but also thought that you would have definitely smelled a FET thermally giving away. But great that it's working now.

Comment: Thank you guys! Yes I smelt something burning but thought it was from somewhere else.

Comment: I am using 3x 2N7000 to drive 3 RGB channels of a 9 led segment strip.  At first all 3 channels fully turned off when arduino pin was LOW, but now all 3 MOSFETs allow power to go through even when Gate is grounded (about 6V, with a 12V source, and common ground to arduino).  how could these fail so quickly? am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the device connected correctly, and the Arduino ground is commoned with the 12V supply ground, the next suspect is electrostatic damage to either the MOSFET or the Arduino.

If the Arduino pin swings from 0V to 5V when disconnected from the MOSFET, replace the MOSFET. And use proper anti-static working procedures this time.

Also note that most Peltier coolers take 6-10A, so with an ON resistance of 0.1 ohms the MOSFET will dissipate 3.6 to 10 watts, and die rather quickly unless you mount it to an appropriate heatsink (say 5C to 10C per watt)

Answer (score 2):

For your connection to work,  you must have a common ground for the MOSFET and the Arduino. The MOSFET's Source must go to the common ground. Also your (12V) power supply's ground must be the same ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP7ugE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing a 10k resistor. Just run a 10k resistor from ground to mosfet pin no. 1 (digital pin 4) and then it will work fine!

here is the working example and circuit diagram.

http://www.circuitmagic.com/arduino/run-small-brushed-motor-for-mini-quadcopter/

Comment: Tried using 10k resistor as suggested, does not seem to work.

Comment: is Arduino ground and 12 v supply ground is commoned ?

Comment: yes they are... I power the Arduino using the 12 VDC power supply.